# Update query on MySQL only when two conditions exist, otherwise Insert (

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this:

```
ID ID_USER SOURCE CONTENT
```

or just:

```
CREATE TABLE `p_l_0215` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

I want to update when **ID_USER**=*Value1* and **SOURCE**=*'default'* if this condition do not exist i want to insert. I know the method when i have a duplicate key, but in this table **ID_USER** neither **SOURCE** could be UNIQUE. So how can i solve this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: but are the pairs (user_id, source) unique across the table?

Comment: then add a unique constraint on the pair and go with insert on duplicate key update, which is supposed to be used in such cases

Comment: @newtover can you please show me how?

Comment: I do not actually understand what you are going to insert when there is no (user_id, DEFAULT(source)) pair? Any other value? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @newtover if you check the answer gave by redmoon7777 is exactly what i need, but working.

Comment: My solution seems to do the same but assumes the default value is taken from the column defaults, but it is rather easy to pass the default value explicitly.

Comment: @newtover in this particular case i need to use something more like redmoon7777's solution because i cant "alter" the table like you suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create the procedure

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE smartInsert(given_id_user bigint(20),given_source varchar(50), given_content text) 
BEGIN 

IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM p_l_0215 WHERE `id_user`=given_id_user AND `source`=given_source))
THEN
    UPDATE p_l_0215 SET `content`=given_content WHERE `id_user`=given_id_user AND `source`=given_source;
ELSE
      INSERT INTO p_l_0215 VALUES (null, given_id_user, given_source, given_content);
END IF;
END//
delimiter ;
```

2) then just call it like this `CALL smartInsert(13, 'some_source', 'some content');`

Comment: there is a systax erro but i can see where it is:
query SQL: 

IF( SELECT id
FROM p_l_0215
WHERE id_user =  'Value1'
AND source =  'default' ) = NULL 
THEN 
INSERT INTO p_l_0215( id, id_user, source, content ) 
VALUES (

NULL ,  'Value1',  'default',  'content'
);

Messaggio di MySQL: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT id FROM p_l_0215 WHERE id_user = 'Value1' AND source = 'default') = N' at line 1

Comment: it shouldn't be **source = 'default') = N...** it should be **source = 'default') IS NULL...**

Comment: i also change that but the same syntax error, any other idea?

Comment: I'm really sorry, we just came back home. anyways the procedure didn't work yet?

Comment: no it says that there is an error on the IF statment, i really dont know where the problem is, if i execute just the SELECT it works, if i execute just the INSERT it works, and if i execute just the UPDATE it works!!! but the hole code give me and error, check this screenshoot: http://s14.postimage.org/lvui6nqo1/Immagine.png

Comment: if you check my edit you will find the sql for the table if you want to try it in your server

Comment: ok I explained my answer some more in my edit. see if it helps and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to update the existing pair (user_id, source) if it is already present, otherwise insert a new row. (user_id, source) pairs are unique across the table.

That is you need a) to add a UNIQUE constraint for the pair:

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtable`
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_user_source` USING BTREE(`ID_USER`, `SOURCE`);
```

and b) to write the upsert query as follows (@user_id and @content are variables that you pass to the query):

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (ID_USER, CONTENT)
  VALUES(@user_id, @content)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  CONTENT = VALUES(CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MySql you are using ... if it's 5.0 or higher then you can use

```
INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Look further here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

This only works for MySQL 5.0+

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```